# Excel VBA Comment Query

Tags: vba, excel

So I have tried and failed many times to do this.

I'm trying to write a VBA script that when run will insert a comment in the active cell that says:

[Surname], [First Name]
[Todays date] was [current cell value]

Surnames and First Names should be bold.

If the cell is edited again it would edit the comment and put the above format below the previous comment.

Here is what I have at the moment (bearing in mind it could be very wrong)

```
Sub Test()
Dim UserN As String
Dim commt As String
Dim cmt As Comment

UserN = Application.UserName
Set cmt = ActiveCell.Comment

If ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
commt = UserN & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
  & Chr(10) & Format(Now, strDate) & " was £" & ActiveCell
With Selection

    With Cells(Selection.Row, Selection.Column)
    .ClearComments
    .AddComment
    .Comment.Visible = False
    .Comment.Shape.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle
    .Comment.Text Text:=commt
        With .Comment.Shape.TextFrame
            ' Username
            With .Characters(1, Len(UserN)).Font
                .Bold = True
            End With

            With .Characters.Font
                .Size = 12
            End With
        End With
    .Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    End With
End With

Else

  commt.txt = commt.txt & Chr(10) UserN & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
  & Chr(10) & Format(Now, strDate) & " was £" & ActiveCell

With Selection

    With Cells(Selection.Row, Selection.Column)
    .ClearComments
    .AddComment
    .Comment.Visible = False
    .Comment.Shape.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle
    .Comment.Text Text:=commt
        With .Comment.Shape.TextFrame
            ' Username
            With .Characters(1, Len(UserN)).Font
                .Bold = True
            End With

            With .Characters.Font
                .Size = 12
            End With
        End With
    .Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    End With
End With

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please also note what the problem with this code is. Does it throw an error message, or it doesn't work at all? The more specific your question is the higher the quality of an answer will be.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only major issue is with this line:

```
commt.txt = commt.txt & Chr(10) UserN & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
  & Chr(10) & Format(Now, strDate) & " was £" & ActiveCell
```

It is using the variable 'commt' as if it were a comment object, but is simply a string. It's also missing a '&' and a '_' line separator. I believe the line should be:

```
commt = cmt.text & Chr(10) & UserN & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Format(Now, strDate) & " was £" & ActiveCell
```